# How can I maximize the lifetime of my cleats

Tags: cleat

I'm using look kéo cleats. My right one is much more worn down than the left one. Almost to the point where I don't think it will have any edge showing on the front lip.

I do walk in them a bit, but usually in grass or on smooth tile. In both conditions I would think it's the heel hitting the floor more, so the front wearing quicker is a surprise to me.

What are some causes of early wearing on cleats and how can I prevent them?

Comment: Not really an answer, but as you walk in them, have you considered switching to something more suited to walking such as SPD or other MTB styles?

Comment: Simple answer is don't walk on them.  Put them on at the bike, then pull the bike to you rather than take a step.  I have a piece of polystychrene on the floor where I dismount, and I stand on that to take my shoes off.  Works well for me.   In other locations you can stand on your toes until you remove the shoes.    I don't know why they don't make road cleats out of alloy or something harder-wearing.

Comment: I've been wearing look cleats for a couple months now, and one does wear faster.  For me its my right.  So I paid attention and noticed when I dismount I put the right foor down then get off the right side, producing a quarter turn scrape mostly on the toe and teh front of the cleat. This adds up over time to the damage you've seen.   Consider swapping cleats left for right, and notice what you're doing more of on the worn side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get special covers for your cleats that make it easier to walk and extend their useful life.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000UDBLQO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UDBLQO)

Comment: I can recommend these covers from personal experience.

Comment: While these are helpful, they wouldn't help with wear from standing on one foot during a stop. I asked these questions on B.SE to have reference points in case anyone else searches for this too, so I'll wait to accept for a bit.

Comment: Round here cleats are $15 a pair, and the covers are $35 a pair.  I can buy two whole sets of cleats for the cost of covers - its not worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer that you're looking for, but I find that Speedplay cleats covered with [Keep-on Kovers](http://www.keeponkovers.com/Product.html) wear very reasonably.

Covers which need to be removed are a hassle. I forget to take them off when I need to and forget to put them on when I need to.

I don't use Keo cleats, so I am not certain, but I believe the design is such that the wear points are impossible to protect when you're on the bike.

Comment: Keo and delta style cleats could last forever, if the rider never ever put a foot down.  The mating surface is on top of the ledges that poke forward and backward from the cleat, and the only wear comes from standing or walking.  Mine last 6-12 months, but a 4 km walk in them ruined some almost new cleats so ~3 months use = 1 km walking on tarmac.